# Missing method call for verify(mock) here

Tags: java, junit

I have a problem with the mockito.
Code to my program

```
public boolean bajaContribuyente(String dni){
        Contribuyente c = em.find(Contribuyente.class, dni);
        if(c!=null){
                em.remove(c);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And the test:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass()throws Exception{

    contribuyenteDAO.setEm(em);;
    when(contribuyenteD.getDni()).thenReturn("4");
    when(em.find(Contribuyente.class, "4")).thenReturn(contribuyenteD);
}

@Test
public void testBajaContribuyente(){        
    contribuyenteDAO.bajaContribuyente("4");
    verify(em).find(Contribuyente.class, "4");
    verify(em).remove(contribuyenteD);
}
```

JUnit say that missing method call for verify(mock), but i dont know why

Comment: Do you have stacktrace or any additional details about error?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to add a static import of Mockito's methods (e.g. verify), like the following:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

Comment: the library is ok. I have more method and it´s good. it doesnt give me more details.

Comment: We'll need to see the full stackTrace and full code example demonstrating the error to help further.  Past work with Mockito suggests that the issue may be in a method called prior to where the error is reported to occur.  To remove that possibility, please construct an example JUnit where these are the only two methods and see if the issue continues to occur.